# Change security-context for method call with spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Currently I'm using spring security and `@PreAuthorize` annotations to secure method calls. Now I want to change the authentication token for a method call like the [run-as authentication replacement](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/runas.html) of spring security allows me to do.

Can I configure the replacement on a per method base? Per annotation, SpEL expression....
If not, would it be possible do figure out in the runAsManager what method is called?
How would I configure the security config attributes for a secured object, at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by implementing my own `RunAsManager` that checks for a custom annotation on the invoked method and returns the appropriate Token.

works great.

Answer (score 7):

I've posted [a detailed article](http://thatjavathing.blogspot.nl/2014/07/spring-security-run-as-example-using.html) on implementing Run-As in conjunction with `@PreAuthorize`.

1) Implement your own `RunAsManager` that creates the `Authentication` to use during method execution based on any custom logic. The example below uses a custom annotation that provides the extra role:

```
public class AnnotationDrivenRunAsManager extends RunAsManagerImpl {

        @Override
        public Authentication buildRunAs(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
            if(!(object instanceof ReflectiveMethodInvocation) || ((ReflectiveMethodInvocation)object).getMethod().getAnnotation(RunAsRole.class) == null) {
                return super.buildRunAs(authentication, object, attributes);
            }

            String roleName = ((ReflectiveMethodInvocation)object).getMethod().getAnnotation(RunAsRole.class).value();

            if (roleName == null || roleName.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            GrantedAuthority runAsAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName);
            List<GrantedAuthority> newAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            // Add existing authorities
            newAuthorities.addAll(authentication.getAuthorities());
            // Add the new run-as authority
            newAuthorities.add(runAsAuthority);

            return new RunAsUserToken(getKey(), authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials(),
                    newAuthorities, authentication.getClass());
        }
    }
```

This implementation will look for a custom `@RunAsRole` annotation on a protected method (e.g. `@RunAsRole("ROLE_AUDITOR")`) and, if found, will add the given authority (`ROLE_AUDITOR` in this case) to the list of granted authorities. `RunAsRole` itself is just a simple custom annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface RunAsRole {
    String value();
}
```

2) Instantiate the manager:

```
<bean id="runAsManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.RunAsManagerImpl">
  <property name="key" value="my_run_as_key"/>
</bean>
```

3) Register it:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" run-as-manager-ref="runAsManager">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>
```

4) Example usage in a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TransactionLogController {

   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_REGISTERED_USER')") //Authority needed to access the method
   @RunAsRole("ROLE_AUDITOR") //Authority added by RunAsManager
   @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions",  method = RequestMethod.GET) //Spring MVC configuration. Not related to security
   @ResponseBody //Spring MVC configuration. Not related to security
   public List<Transaction> getTransactionLog(...) {
    ... //Invoke something in the backend requiring ROLE_AUDITOR
   {

   ... //User does not have ROLE_AUDITOR here
}
```

**EDIT:**
The value of `key` in `RunAsManagerImpl` can be anything you want. Here's the excerpt from [Spring docs](http://springcert.sourceforge.net/sec-3/runas.html) on its use:

> To ensure malicious code does not create a `RunAsUserToken` and present
>   it for guaranteed acceptance by the `RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider`,
>   the hash of a key is stored in all generated tokens. The
>   `RunAsManagerImpl` and `RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider` is created in the
>   bean context with the same key:
>
> ```
> <bean id="runAsManager"
>     class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.RunAsManagerImpl">
> ```
>
> ```
> <bean id="runAsAuthenticationProvider"
>     class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider">
> ```
>
> By using the
>   same key, each `RunAsUserToken` can be validated it was created by an
>   approved `RunAsManagerImpl`. The `RunAsUserToken` is immutable after
>   creation for security reasons.

Comment: What exactly is that "my_run_as_key" used for? - I can't figure this out. I probably read the same guide you quoted here, but this key just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @DanielBo The value can be anything you want. It's basically a password.
I updated the answer to quote Spring docs on why it is needed.